# Get column names from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Table in my MySQL Database which looks like this:

```
Table: VAAW
Columns:
ID  int(11) PK AI
Voornaam    varchar(45) 
Achternaam  varchar(45) 
Adres   varchar(45) 
Woonplaats  varchar(45)
```

I am using this table in the following php code:

```
$strSQL     = "SELECT * FROM NAW.VAAW";
$objQuery   = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
$Voornaam   = $objResult["Voornaam"];
$Achternaam = $objResult["Achternaam"];
$Adres      = $objResult["Adres"];
$Woonplaats = $objResult["Woonplaats"];

$string     = $_POST['naam'];

$vaaw       = array("(voornaam)", "(achternaam)", "(woonplaats)", "(adres)");
$vervang    = array("$Voornaam", "$Achternaam", "$Woonplaats","$Adres");

echo str_replace($vaaw, $vervang, $string);
echo '<br>';
}
```

What I use this for:
I have a form where I can add some tekst in a textbox and when I submit it will echo the result. For example if the Column 'Voornaam' contains the row 'Jack' and when I type in the textbox in my form: Hey (voornaam), it should output: Hey Jack.

I don't really know how to ask this question so I will give an example. If I for some reason want to change a column name in my database I will have to change this source code according to the column name changes.

The example:

If I change the column name 'voornaam' to 'Vnaam' I will also have to change

```
$Voornaam  = $objResult["Voornaam"];
```

to

```
$Voornaam  = $objResult["Vnaam"];
```

So my question is if there is any way to have some sort of standard for like the 1st column, 2nd colum etc. so I can add that in the code and will not have to change the source code every time I change a column name. Maybe there is a query function to do this? I know this question is kinda vague but I hope you understand, if not feel free to ask in the comments. Any help would be great since I have no clue how to do this!

***NOTE:***
I know I should't be using mysql_* and I will switch to PDO later. So please don't mention that again.

Comment: You can use mysql*_fetch_row to get the result as an enumerated array. You can also use the system tables (in information schema) to get the column details. But I would suggest that changing the column names is something to be avoided, and any way to avoid this causing major problems will either destroy readability and / or destroy performance.

Comment: `I (...) will not have to change the source code every time I change a column name` The point is : you shouldn't have to change a column name.

Comment: the standard is to design your database correctly and dont change the names. It really doesn't matter what you call the columns, so changing their name is not necessary unless you display that name on the front end. in that instance change the interface!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use `print_r($objResult)` you will see that you have results with both `numerical` and `strings` keys.

So, instead of `$Voornaam  = $objResult["Vnaam"]` you can use `$Voornaam  = $objResult[0]`

Comment: And also note that he wants to use this, because somehow he's changing his table quite a lot. With this, you'd have to change your index every time you add columns. (note: columns that you are not adding at the end, but i.e. somewhere in between)

Comment: You're right @NiekvanderSteen . To be more dynamically you can use a configuration file where you will define the indexes of each column in your table.. So instead of using `$objResult[0]` will be better to use `$objResult[$VoornamIndex]` where `$VoornamIndex` could be 0, 1, 2 depending on your table modifications.

Comment: Well, let me explain what I am using this for. I have a form where I can add some tekst in a textbox and when I submit it will echo the result. For example if the Column 'Voornaam' contains the row 'Jack' and when I type in the textbox in my form: Hey (voornaam), it should output: Hey Jack. If I use your solution it will ouput: Hey 1

Answer (score 1):

You can call columns by there index like :

```
$Voornaam  = $objResult[0]; //if the first column of the table is "voornaam"
```

But you have to know the column order...

The [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function can have a second param like : **MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, et MYSQL_BOTH** default is MYSQL_BOTH, and it return an array with for each column, a key with the column name , and another one with column index.